# How can I deploy Puppet Master configuration files from my build server?

Tags: deployment, teamcity, puppet

I have a (RedHat) Puppet Master server, with Puppet Master's configuration files in `/etc/puppet`.

I've placed the entire contents of `/etc/puppet` into source control and would like my CI server (TeamCity on Windows) to be able to deploy changes to the Puppet Master server.

How can I accomplish this?

I have an idea that I can use scp, but copying to `/etc/puppet` would require sudo privileges.  At the same time I would like a simple setup.

If there are any alternative or better ways of deploying puppet master configuration files, those answers would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that the whole `/etc/puppet` should be subjected to CI.

It might be more appropriate to move your `$manifestdir` and `$modulepath` instances outside that tree and make some CI client their owner. Just be careful to ensure read privileges to the `puppet` user.

This way, you could rely on SSH without too much of a security hole (but then, opening up your manifests for writing is always risky), and avoid the need to make the master configuration writeable to a non-root user.

Comment: This sounds useful, can you explain a bit about ensuring read privileges for the puppet user? I know I can `chown` a directory to the ci-user, would I then `chmod 666` the directory so puppet can read it?

Comment: That would be a Bad Idea! Never make your manifests world writeable. Even world readable should be avoided in some cases. Make them `ci-user:puppet` with mode `2640` (SGID bit so new files get the group, although this can be tricky with git - there are some git config settings you want to check).